# XML Error Formatting (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

The Xml have any issue about properties length?

when i create this xml in php always get format error, is this correct?

```
<feed xmlns="http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/" xml:lang="en-US">
<Row Id="1" Name="Any" Under="1016" Description="Pancetta beef ribs capicola ribeye, shankle leberkäse chicken fatback jerky shank ground round turkey turducken. Salami andouille chuck, pancetta tenderloin meatball frankfurter biltong. Jowl venison tri-tip pancetta meatloaf, swine frankfurter ball tip filet mignon salami tail boudin tenderloin kielbasa chuck. Tri-tip tail andouille, tongue chicken flank shankle corned beef salami t-bone meatloaf sausage meatball frankfurter. Prosciutto ham meatloaf, shoulder corned beef tenderloin rump venison ribeye kielbasa drumstick brisket pork chop pork loin. Short loin sirloin pastrami bresaola, pork chop pork belly turducken strip steak t-bone prosciutto meatloaf. Bresaola leberkäse short ribs, shankle frankfurter hamburger tongue." />
</feed>
```

Comment: The length of the Description attribute's value should not be an issue at all here. Is it not the xml:lang attribute, by chance? You need to reference the namespace before you can use it. Doesn't removing xml:lang make the error disappear?

Comment: Found the error was the xml:lang two,but in the middle of the text was some " lost in there...

Answer (score 0):

Try converting all the non-ASCII characters to numeric HTML entities.
E.g. "ä" into "&#228;"